# Quantify time watched (or not watched) with multiple overlapping sessions

Tags: r, datetime, grouping, data-manipulation

I have a dataset where I have the start and end time for when multiple users collected data. This is a subset of the dataset:

```
  user_login       session_start        session_stop observation_name observation_value    observation_time
1      user1 2020-02-24 09:30:00 2020-02-24 09:35:00   session_status             start 2020-02-24 09:30:00
2      user1 2020-02-24 09:30:00 2020-02-24 09:35:00          species              bird 2020-02-24 09:31:00
3      user1 2020-02-24 09:30:00 2020-02-24 09:35:00          species            lizard 2020-02-24 09:32:00
4      user2 2020-02-24 09:33:00 2020-02-24 09:36:00   session_status             start 2020-02-24 09:33:00
5      user2 2020-02-24 09:33:00 2020-02-24 09:36:00          species              bird 2020-02-24 09:34:00
6      user1 2020-02-24 09:30:00 2020-02-24 09:35:00   session_status              stop 2020-02-24 09:35:00
7      user2 2020-02-24 09:33:00 2020-02-24 09:36:00   session_status              stop 2020-02-24 09:36:00
```

```
structure(list(user_login = c("user1", "user1", "user1", "user2", 
"user2", "user1", "user2"), session_start = c("2020-02-24 09:30:00", 
"2020-02-24 09:30:00", "2020-02-24 09:30:00", "2020-02-24 09:33:00", 
"2020-02-24 09:33:00", "2020-02-24 09:30:00", "2020-02-24 09:33:00"
), session_stop = c("2020-02-24 09:35:00", "2020-02-24 09:35:00", 
"2020-02-24 09:35:00", "2020-02-24 09:36:00", "2020-02-24 09:36:00", 
"2020-02-24 09:35:00", "2020-02-24 09:36:00"), observation_name = c("session_status", 
"species", "species", "session_status", "species", "session_status", 
"session_status"), observation_value = c("start", "bird", "lizard", 
"start", "bird", "stop", "stop"), observation_time = c("2020-02-24 09:30:00", 
"2020-02-24 09:31:00", "2020-02-24 09:32:00", "2020-02-24 09:33:00", 
"2020-02-24 09:34:00", "2020-02-24 09:35:00", "2020-02-24 09:36:00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I have multiple sessions from multiple users for multiple days. I want to be able to quantify, for each hour of each day, how much of that hour was watched (and not watched). 
Problem is, like the example data shows, users sometimes overlap.

I've tried to think through a tidyverse solution, but haven't gotten anywhere.

The end goal is would be for each hour to have the number of minutes watched. So, for this subset of data would look like this:

```
             hour min_watched
1 2020-02-24 9:00           6
```

```
structure(list(hour = "2020-02-24 9:00", min_watched = "6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Could you clarify further what your end result should look like, given your example data above? What would the final resulting data frame be?

Comment: @Ben I edited the question to include what end result I'm lokoing for

Comment: I think you may have a calendar problem on your hands, I once made a blog post that solved for something very similar, https://twosidesdata.netlify.app/2020/01/12/google-interview-question-in-r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be efficient, but I believe may be something to work from. It uses `lubridate` / `tidyverse`. I suspect a `data.table` approach might be better.

First, make sure you have your times in `POSIXct` format. Then, you can collapse your time ranges as there is overlap.

Next, create a sequence of hourly intervals based on the minimum and maximum times from your time ranges.

Finally, to create your result with number of minutes for each hour in the hourly intervals sequence, use `intersect` between the intervals.

Please let me know if this is close to what you had in mind.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Determine overlapping ranges of times
time_ranges <- df %>%
  mutate_at(c("session_start", "session_stop", "observation_time"), as.POSIXct) %>%
  arrange(session_start) %>% 
  group_by(g = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(session_start)) > cummax(as.numeric(session_stop)))[-n()])) %>%
  summarise(start = min(session_start), stop = max(session_stop)) %>%
  mutate(interval = interval(start, stop))

# Create hourly intervals needed
hour_start <- seq(from = floor_date(min(time_ranges$start), unit = "hours"), 
                to = ceiling_date(max(time_ranges$stop), unit = "hours"), 
                by = "hours")
hour_int <- interval(hour_start, hour_start + hours(1))

# Determine overlap between hourly intervals and determined time ranges
data.frame(
  hour = hour_start,
  min_watched = sapply(seq_along(hour_int), function(x) sum(as.numeric(as.duration(intersect(hour_int[x], time_ranges$interval)), "minutes"), na.rm = TRUE))
)
```

**Edit**:

If you wish to use 30 minute intervals instead of one hour, you can create a sequence of 30 minute intervals:

```
# Create half hour intervals
half_hour_start <- seq(from = floor_date(min(time_ranges$start), unit = "hours"), 
                to = ceiling_date(max(time_ranges$stop), unit = "hours"), 
                by = "30 min")
half_hour_int <- interval(half_hour_start, half_hour_start + minutes(30))
```

I believe the rest of the code should be the same.

**Edit (8/10/2020)**: To also include time ranges for each hour, try this when creating the final data.frame:

```
data.frame(
  hour = hour_start,
  min_watched = sapply(seq_along(hour_int), function(x) sum(as.numeric(as.duration(intersect(hour_int[x], time_ranges$interval)), "minutes"), na.rm = TRUE)),
  time_range = sapply(seq_along(hour_int), function(x) as.character(intersect(hour_int[x], time_ranges$interval)))
)
```

Or, if you just want the times, you can do your own formatting and drop the dates using a custom function, for example:

```
get_range <- function(hour, interval) {
  time_int <- intersect(hour, interval)
  return(paste(format(int_start(time_int), "%H:%M"), "-", format(int_end(time_int), "%H:%M")))
}
```

Then you can use this when creating the final data.frame:

```
time_range = sapply(seq_along(hour_int), function(x) get_range(hour_int[x], time_ranges$interval))
```

Comment: Thank you for this Ben! I haven't had the chance to implement this, but I'll hopefully be able to tomorrow or next week. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi @Ben looks like everything works, but then the last section doesn't -- I'm left with a bunch of 0's in the "min_watched" column, which can't be right.

Comment: it did end up working! It didn't work when I tried to adjust the time interval to a half-hour after talking with some colleagues about the most appropriate interval. I'm not sure what I did wrong..., but thank you thank you!

Comment: will do! One more question before I let you go (if I may!), does this code take into account that some people might be watching than the specified interval. For instance, I have many people that watched longer than 30 minute intervals

Comment: It looks like it should...I just altered your test data, and had one session start/stop go from 13:10 to 15:20, and it gave 50 minutes to 13:00-14:00, 60 minutes to 14:00-15:00, and 20 minutes from 15:00-16:00, which sounds correct. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: @Rachael Also see edited answer if you want to use 30 minute intervals instead of one hour.

Comment: also looks like it should on my end. Thanks for the edited answer! Everything looks perfect now :)

Comment: I wanted to let you know that the last line of code didn't work when I tried it again today. But then, I specified lubridate::as.duration() and lubridate::intersect() and it worked. I think R was getting a bit confused.

Comment: @Rachael Glad you mentioned that. Functions like `intersect` are included in a number of different packages that may get masked.

Comment: I've been using this code successfully and it's been great! Now, in addition to the duration of time watched (ex: 21 minutes), I'd like to have the time frame within each interval that is watch (e.x. 10:00-10:21). Is that possible?

Comment: One quick thing to try: in your final data.frame call, add `time_range = sapply(seq_along(hour_int), function(x) as.character(intersect(hour_int[x], time_ranges$interval)))` under `min_watched = sapply...` - I'll edit the answer to demonstrate. `as.character` added otherwise will return a numeric duration. Not entirely sure this would work, but worth a try...

Comment: Hi @Ben thanks for the edit. It is currently not working for me, but I'm trying to figure out why. I receive this warning: Error in data.frame(hour = hour_start, time_range = sapply(seq_along(hour_int),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 575, 397

Comment: Hi @Rachael - I'm wondering if it might be easier to either edit your question with what you are trying so I can reproduce at my end, or submit a new question. You can use `dput` to provide a subset of your data (such as `dput(head(df, 10))` for first 10 rows), and share the code you are using that gives you an error.

Comment: When I run just time_range = , I get "NA--NA" and [,573] values